# DataLoader issue : RNN module weights are not part of single contiguous chunk of memory

Tags: python, lstm, pytorch, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to build an LSTM model for time series data. The details of dataset:
Input data is time series with 800 subjects, each having a 2D array data of 60 rows and 200 columns. I loaded the entire data as a Tensor of shape `[800,60,200]` and labels for the classification problem is of shape `[800,1]`.
I made a dictionary of the data using the following code :

```
class DataCurate(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, l1,l2, transform=None):
        self.l1=l1
        self.l2=l2
        self.transform=transform
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.l1)
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        array=self.l1[index]
        label=self.l2[index]
        sample = {'time_data': array, 'labels': label}
        return sample
```

the data and labels are in variables x & y. I call data=Datacurate(x,y)

Later on I build and LSTM model for classification problem using the code:

```
class RNNModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes):
    super(RNNModel, self).__init__()
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.num_layers = num_layers
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers,batch_first=True) 
    self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_layers, bias=True) 
    self.softmax = nn.LogSoftmax()

    def forward(self, x)
        self.lstm.flatten_parameters()
        out_packed, state = self.lstm(x)  # RNN
        print("lstm output size: {out.size()}"+str(out_packed.size()))
        out = self.linear(out_packed[-1])  # linear transform
    print("linear output size {out.size()} "+str(out.size()))
    log_probs = F.log_softmax(out,dim=1)
    print("softmax output size {log_probs.size()}"+str(log_probs.size()))
        return log_probs
```

This gives me an error when I run the training script:

```
UserWarning: RNN module weights are not part of single contiguous chunk of memory. This means they need to be compacted at every call, possibly greatly increasing memory usage. To compact weights again call flatten_parameters().
  out_packed, state = self.lstm(x)  # RNN
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main_2.py", line 100, in <module>
    output = model(train_inputs.transpose(0,1))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 477, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/media/iab/disk_a/meghal/test/quickdraw_tutorial_dataset_v1/pytorch_RNN_examples/model.py", line 26, in forward
    out_packed, state = self.lstm(x)  # RNN
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 477, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py", line 192, in forward
    output, hidden = func(input, self.all_weights, hx, batch_sizes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/_functions/rnn.py", line 324, in forward
    return func(input, *fargs, **fkwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/torch/nn/_functions/rnn.py", line 288, in forward
    dropout_ts)
RuntimeError: param_from.type() == param_to.type() ASSERT FAILED at /pytorch/aten/src/ATen/native/cudnn/RNN.cpp:491, please report a bug to PyTorch. parameter types mismatch
```

I don't know what this means and how do I resolve it. I am completely new to LSTM.

Comment: I'm afraid you have to add more information. With this code given I cannot reproduce your error. However in your traceback it shows, you are actually using `transpose` this is probably why you get the `UserWarning` you should try to store the data already in the needed shape - if you still really want to use transpose you can do `train_inputs.transpose(0,1).contiguous()`. This should let you get rid off the warning you posted in the title. However this warning may not be related to the  `RuntimeError: parameter types mismatch` Try adding more information without letting grow the code to large!

Comment: See also: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)